# Facebook sharer params

Tags: facebook, social-networking

Where can I find full docs for using http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php ? I want to know all aviable params to this url for sharing something.

P.S. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ gave me no info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no documentation because the new way for sharing is the Like button. But you can add do http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=*yourURL*.

To specify the image and the description, you have to add the following meta data in the header of your website.

**Image**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="URL of your image" />
```

**Description**

```
<meta name="description" content="Your description" />
```

Facebook will use the meta og:image to find the image and the meta description for the description.

Cheers

Comment: but how can I specify the description and image?

Answer (score 0):

The [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) for the sharer are pretty sparse and virtually non-existent. You **used** to be able to send a whole host of params to the Facebook sharer.php

Facebook have since made an update (feb/mar 2014) and it now looks at the OpenGraph tags above anything else. See [response from FB developer](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/357750474364812/?comment_id=308955395926697)

They now recommend using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) method of sharing.